# Filtering Drupal 6 View based on multiple content types

Tags: views, entities

This is a repost of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489525/filtering-drupal-6-view-based-on-multiple-content-types

I have a drupal 6 installation, and am trying to limit a view with Filters.  I've tried everything I can think of, and can't seem to get it to work.  Here is the situation.

I have a project, and that project has several pages, and those pages have several sub-pages

```
PROJECT
---------->Page
------------------>subpage
```

I want to filter out the results based on the following criteria:

```
Recently Modified of subpage is "YES" (working)
Project of a page is not a specific project NID (working)
Checkbox inside content type project is not checked (not working, values are "no" 
for "Don't ignore" and "yes" for "Ignore"
```

So, using Filters, I'd like to see if the project is checked, and if it is, ignore all pages and subpages of that project.  I hope this makes sense.

Please see the link for images.  Until I have 10 rep, I can't post them here.

`(Page) Content: Project` has been removed.  It is just `Content: Project`

Comment: Hi there, could you clarify your Project --> Page --> subpage setup a little bit more?  I'm gathering that Project is a content type.  What exactly are these pages and subpages?  Are they just nodes of that content type or something like that?

Comment: Boriana - `Page` and `SubPage` are both content types as well.  Basically think of it like a Book.  A project is a book, then "page" would be more like a chapter, and subpage would be the actual page of the chapter.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Bump Bump...@Boriana - Any help on this?

Comment: Sorry, I just can't quite picture how these content types are connected and what your view looks like so far.  Are these connected to each other via node references or entity references?  Is this view a view of subpages and you have relationships setup to connect the subpage to its corresponding page, so you can get to the project field of the page?  If you can put some more info about how you have the view setup so far, I think I'd be able to notice what you need to do to get it over this last hurdle....

Comment: The views are all custom, done by another company, and I'm picking up where they left off.  They are all done by node reference.  And custom tpl.php pages.  It's hard to explain.  Basically this is a fresh view, from scratch, trying to limit pages within a certain project from showing up if there is something checked in that project edit page.  Hope this helps.  I can't think of another way to describe.

Comment: Try just printing out the value of that field in your view before using it as a filter.  That way you can make sure your relationships are working properly.  Are the values of the checkbox printing out properly if you just include them as fields in the view?

Comment: Ok, I added the checkboxes as fields using relationship of "Project", and the values are NOT printing.  Not sure why not.  Any help?